# cannot find module videogular2/core,videogular2/controls

Tags: angular

How to import videogular2  controls,overlay-play modules from **videogular2** as it doesnot have **index.js** or **videogular.js** file.
i have tried the following code:

```
npm install videogular2
```

but unable to find **videogular2.js** or **index.js** in the videogular2 node module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main file of videogular2 is **core.js**, not index.js. You will have to import this, along with **controls.js** and **overlay-play.js**, which are all found at the root directory.

If you're using **angular-cli**, these are the configurations that worked for me:

**angular-cli-build.js**

```
module.exports = function(defaults) {
  return new Angular2App(defaults, { 
   vendorNpmFiles: [
     ...
     'videogular2/dist/**/*',
     'videogular2/core.+(ts|js)',
     'videogular2/controls.+(ts|js)',
     'videogular2/overlay-play.+(ts|js)'
     ...
   ]
  });
};
```

**system-config.ts**

```
const map: any = {
 ...
 'videogular2': 'vendor/videogular2'
 ...
};

const packages: any = {
  ...
  'videogular2': {
     main: 'core.js'
  }
  ...
};
```

And in your angular2 class, you can import it as follows:

```
import { VgPlayer } from 'videogular2/core';
import { VgControls } from 'videogular2/controls';
```

--

Lastly, an added tip as I've encountered a problem with a missing VgAPI provider.

In my angular2 component, I had to do the following:

```
import { VgAPI } from 'videogular2/core';

@Component({
  ...
  providers: [
   VgAPI
  ]
  ...
})
class MyComponent { }
```

Answer (score 31):

**Importing these solves my problem**

```
import { VgCoreModule } from 'videogular2/compiled/core';
import { VgControlsModule } from 'videogular2/compiled/controls';
import { VgOverlayPlayModule } from 'videogular2/compiled/overlay-play';
import { VgBufferingModule } from 'videogular2/compiled/buffering';
```

Comment: Version 6.3.0 was videogular2/core and now it's videogular2/compiled/core. Same for other imports

Comment: Thanks! the 'compiled' bit of the import statement was missing from the Videogular getting started guide.

Answer (score 0):

Add this lib. in angular-cli-build.js

```
module.exports = function(defaults) {
  return new Angular2App(defaults, {
    vendorNpmFiles: [
      ...
      'videogular2/**/*',
      ...
    ]
  });
};
```

Comment: i tried this.. but it is not working. can you please suggest something else.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but the solutions from @Apharanes and @Sureshreddy were not valid for me. I do not have a file named angular-cli-build.js.

The solution was very simple. It just meant adding "--save" to the install:

```
npm install videogular2 --save
```

I found it when I did an "npm list videogular". It gave me an "extraneous" error. Looking this error up told me that I had installed the package but that since it was not present in my package.json, it considered it "extraneous".

Answer (score 0):

For me it was a problem with node's version.
The last version of videogular (7.0.1 today) supports only node version >= 10 :

Extract of their package.json :

```
"engines": {
    "node": ">=10.9.0 <11.0.0"
  },
```

You can use a previous version of videogular (6.4.0) or update your node's version.